# How to run Blender on Linux from command line without admin permissions from command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, centos-7, blender, render

I am trying to make a render farm on CentOS 7, which will probably be slow, but it will be working 7/24, and I want to use my university's remote server for that purpose.

- I have no admin permissions, but I've downloaded the blender `tar.xz` file and unpacked it, however `./blender --help` gives a permission denied error

How can I set up a system to render my `.blend` file on my local space given by the university?

Comment: Is the `blend` file marked as executable (+x) in its file permissions? Do you know whether the server's admins allow users to run their own software? (Have you tried asking them about this problem?) If you copy a regular binary (e.g. /bin/whoami or /bin/id) to your home directory and try to run that, does it work or do you get the same error message?

Comment: ''file blender'' tells me it is executable.

Comment: `file` describes the file's contents, it doesn't tell you anything about permission bits. Try `ls -l`.

Comment: i cannot ask them about this but if i can make them happen it all good, necer tried running regular binary files have nothing to test on atm. I can run my own c++, python codes

Comment: Usually C++ compilers output regular binary files. If you can run those, you _should_ be able to run Blender from the same location, so it's most likely just a problem with the specific file's permissions. (Though if you're given access to several distinct directories, like /home vs /scratch vs /tmp, it's still possible that some of them allow programs to be executed while others have noexec set.)

Comment: -rw-r--r--. 1 is written besides my blender, executable file, whats my best shot then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files, regardless of their contents, are only allowed to be executed if you have the `x` permission on them.

If you're the owner of the file, use `chmod` to change its permissions:

```
chmod a+x blend
```

Answer (score 0):

The .exe file will start the installation. Choose where to install Blender and set MS-Windows to run in the menu, and you can already open .blend files using Blender. You must have administrator rights on your operating system to install Blender. It creates many [frames over multiple machines](https://www.forgehub.net/nebula/blender-render-farm/) so that you don't burden your PC. If you use a .zip file, you unzip it manually to the folder you want to use. From there, you double-click on the executable file to start Blender. With this option, you can have multiple versions of Blender without conflict, as they are not actually installed on the system.

Comment: Question is about Linux.

Comment: -1 because the title says it's about Linux, the first sentence says it's about Linux, comments are Linux-centric and an accepted answer for Linux was posted a year ago, yet you've posted about Windows. This answer is obviously wrong.